# What typ of Diode would I use ? I don't know much about Electronics.

Tags: diodes

I have a motorcycle that is running a 12V system. My question is, What type of diode would I use for my cooling fans for my radiators. The power comes from the ECU on my bike. I want to install another positive wire and switch to the end of the power wire on the ECU power wire and a switch so I can keep the fans running even when the ECU turns off the voltage to that system if need be. The Power wire is connected to a relay and then on to the fans. I would like to Have the switch power in the same line just before the relay. I hope someone can understand my crappy explanation.

Comment: A picture says a thousand words. Add a schematic of the existing system and your proposed modification.

Comment: I'm trying to keep the switch voltage from going into the ECU

Comment: It is pretty much impossible to understand your question. Like Ignacio suggested, post a drawing of now and one of what you intend to change it to.

Comment: Is the ECU switching a relay, or is it supplying all the power for the fan?

Answer (score 1):

Taking a guess at what your asking. At the fan end there is power supplied to turn it (regardless if it comes from the ecu or relay). You'll need two diodes of sufficient current and voltage ratings (depends on how much current the fan takes and what sort of back emf might be generated when turning the fan off) connected as shown below. This stops either feed from supplying the other.The types shown are schottky types (low forward voltage drops). I'd also recommend some form of indicator to show you are overriding the ecu.

[image]

If your switching the relay it depends on how the relay is powered.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jim Dearden, Your a genius ! Yes I'm just wanting to keep voltage from going back to the ECU. It would be a separate power wire and switch.  Is there a difference, say for a 12V system diode that would be needed? I'm stupid like I said. I really want to thank you for your time Sir.

Comment: ok I read your answer a couple times and it is making more sense to me now.